# VideoJS live RTMP stream, player and video size issue

Tags: html, video, rtmp, video.js

I have setup a page with a videojs html5 player that automatically starts to play a remote RTMP live stream.  It works.

When I start the stream the video appears as a tiny box in the top left of the player.  The player is 1280x720 and the video is streaming from a computer or android phone at any resolution, but it also starts in the top left corner.

I haven't measured the resolution of the video in the corner but I'd guess it's about 40x40.  When I select the fullscreen option the video stretches to full screen.  When I shut off fullscreen the  video correctly fills in the player.

I would expect the video to start and fill the player right away without having to fullscreen/restore it.  Any advice or direction would be greatly appreciated it.

This is what I'm working with

```html
<html>
<head>
<title> Stream Player </title>
 <link href="video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="video.js"></script>
  <script>
    videojs.options.flash.swf = "video-js.swf";
  </script>
</head>
<body bgcolor=000000>
 <center>
  <font face="verdana" color=993333><h1>Test</h1></font>
   <video id="livestream" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered"
     controls autoplay preload="auto" width="1280" height="720"
     data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
      <source src="rtmp://webserver.example:1935/live/streamname" type="rtmp/mp4">
   </video>
 </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I switched my search terms on google from to include "squished" and got some helpful results: https://github.com/videojs/video-js-swf/issues/55